# Apache caching urls, RewriteEngine causing problems

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I was trying out the Apache Rewrite Engine, but was having problems because it cached it's responses. Now if I change the file, it does not do what the file says, but does what it did when I tried the same url before.

For example, I tried to type in

```
localhost/api
```

but I had not yet set a rule that would match that. The server gave me a 404 error. I tried to add a rule that would work with this url:

```
RewriteRule api/? api.php [L]
```

but it still gave me the same error. If I try an address like localhost/lapi which I didn't enter before I added the rule, it works. Is there a way to clear this cache and restart? I tried restarting apache using `apachectl -k restart` and `apachectl -k graceful` but I still had the same problem. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, depending on the context of your rule, you may need a leading slash as in:

`RewriteRule api/? /api.php [L]`

Regarding the caching, do you have [mod_cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html) enabled? If so, disable it and restart your server. mod_rewrite does not do any caching on its own. Also be sure to completely clear your browser cache and be aware that if you are not accessing your server over the same local network, there may be other caching taking place along the way.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be caused by the `MultiViews` option, see [Apache doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#multiviews). Try omitting `Option MultiViews` from `httpd.conf` or add `Options -MultiViews` to `.htaccess`.

(The `MultiViews` option enables Apache to choose automaticaly between several versions of the file based on the file name extension and content preferences present in the HTTP request (i.e. something you probably don't want to happen). It can lead to this kind of bizzare failure when a rewrite rule just removes the script's extension.)